# c# generic: is there any difference in declarations: myFunc<T>(T arg) where T: myClass VS myFunc(myClass arg)

Tags: c#, generics

Is there any difference between function definition with generic and where clause, that specifies constraint on the type as "myClass" and function definition, that use "myClass" in the common way.

```
void myFunc<T>(T arg) where T: myClass
```

vs definition:

```
void myFunc(myClass arg)
```

Why(When) should I use generic in function definition, if I set constraints "where" with class name?

Comment: Very important differences. What about derived classes? A `myFunc<MyDerivedClass>` won't accept `MyClass` values, it's a completely new function explicitly expecting `MyDerivedClass`. What about *structs* that implement interfaces instead of deriving from a base class? If you tried to pass a struct as an object, you'd force the value to get wrapped in an object. The compiler creates a new method for every generic method with the specified type parameters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "The compiler creates a new method for every generic method with the specified type parameters" - no it doesn't. The *runtime* has optimizations for different sets of type arguments, at least in some cases (but last time I looked, not for different reference types). But the *compiler* only emits a single method implementation.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, but I guess I tried to simplify this too much.